# Is it possible to access static methods of a class by multiple object instances simultaneously?

Tags: java

Example:

```
ThisClass.staticMethod(Object... parameters);
```

will be accessed by multiple instances of other objects and simultaneously.

Will there be any dependencies with this other objects when they are using the same static method at the same time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only if the method uses static Objects or the arguments are shared by the other instances.

Example: Math.max(int a, int b) is a static method but does not use any static objects, so there are no dependencies.

Example 2: Here all invocations share the same result variable, two parallel calls to staticMethod can cause wrong results.

```
private static int result = 0;
private static int staticMethod(Object... args)
{
      result = args.length;
      //Do Something
      return result;
}
```

Example 3: This one is Thread safe if none of the arguments are shared, each invocation has its own instance of result.

```
private static int staticMethod(Object... args)
{
    int result = 0;
    result = args.length;
    //Do something
    return result;
}
```

Example 4: This uses the class as a lock to prevent parallel access to the class functions. Only one call to staticMethod executes all others wait

```
private static int result = 0;
private static synchronized int staticMethod(Object... args)
{
      result = args.length;
      //Do Something
      return result;
}
```

Comment: "Only if the method uses static Objects" - I understand what you _mean_ here, but your wording is imprecise. I can easily write a method which is not thread safe, although it does not use any static objects (only a non thread safe singleton :-). I think _"static and/or global"_ is a more precise term.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, all users of the method depend on the class, if this is what you mean.

Moreover, if they are really calling the method simultaneously (i.e. from multiple threads), you may get concurrency problems, depending on what the method actually does. Show us the code, and we may be able to tell more.

Answer (score 1):

A code fragment running concurrently by multiple threads has the potential of causing [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), regardless of where this code is placed (static/non-static method).

You must make sure that the data manipulated by the code tolerates concurrent accesses, and synchronize the code properly if needed.

Answer (score 1):

All objects that call the static methods will be dependent on the class methods, but they won't have dependencies with each other.  If it's possible that your static method will be called by objects from different threads, you will need to make sure that your static method is thread-safe, i.e., you need to using locking to ensure that only one thread at a time accesses any non-stack memory.

Comment: oh so i just need to safe guard non-stack memory objects and if i make a static method like those in the Math class and objects will accessed them simultaneously then is it possible right?

Comment: @Richeve - I would expect that static methods in the Math class don't access any shared information that would be changing; if anything simply using static lookup tables and local data.  If your methods are similar, they may already be thread-safe.  Generally, if methods use shared information that may change or change information that other threads may use, then you need to take care to protect those sections of code so that the information is consistent for each thread while it is in that section.